# How to reserve a core for one thread on windows?

Tags: windows, multicore

I am working on a very time sensitive application which polls a region of shared memory taking action when it detects a change has occurred. Changes are rare but I need to minimize the time from change to action. Given the infrequency of changes I think the CPU cache is getting cold. Is there a way to reserve a core for my polling thread so that it does not have to compete with other threads for either cache or CPU?

Comment: Why don't you stop polling and use a proper synchronisation mechanism?

Answer (score 6):

Thread affinity alone (`SetThreadAffinityMask`) will not be enough. It *does not reserve a CPU core*, but it does the opposite, it *binds the thread* to only the cores that you specify (that is not the same thing!).

By constraining the CPU affinity, you *reduce* the likelihood that your thread will run. If another thread with higher priority runs on the same core, your thread will not be scheduled until that other thread is done (this is how Windows schedules threads).
Without constraining affinity, your thread has a chance of being migrated to another core (taking the last time it was run as metric for that decision). Thread migration is undesirable if it happens often and soon after the thread has run (or while it is running) but it is a harmless, beneficial thing if a couple of dozen milliseconds have passed since it was last scheduled (caches will have been overwritten by then anyway).

You can "kind of" assure that your thread will run by giving it a higher priority class (no guarantee, but high likelihood). If you then use `SetThreadAffinityMask` as well, you have a reasonable chance that the cache is always warm on most common desktop CPUs (which luckily are normally VIPT and PIPT). For the TLB, you will probably be less lucky, but there's nothing you can do about it.

The problem with a high priority thread is that it will starve other threads because scheduling is implemented so it serves higher priority classes first, and as long as these are not satisfied, lower classes get zero. So, the solution in this case must be to block. Otherwise, you may impair the system in an unfavorable way.

Try this:

- create a semaphore and share it with the other process
- set priority to THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL
- block on the semaphore
- in the other process, after writing data, call SignalObjectAndWait on the semaphore with a timeout of 1 (or even zero timeout)
- if you want, you can experiment binding them both to the same core

This will create a thread that will be the first (or among the first) to get CPU time, but it is not running.
When the writer thread calls `SignalObjectAndWait`, it atomically signals and blocks (even if it waits for "zero time" that is enough to reschedule). The other thread will wake from the Semaphore and do its work. Thanks to its high priority, it will not be interrupted by other "normal" (that is, non-realtime) threads. It will keep hogging CPU time until done, and then block again on the semaphore. At this point, `SignalObjectAndWait` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Task Manager, you can set the "affinity" of processes.

You would have to set the affinity of your time-critical app to core 4, and the affinity of all the other processes to cores 1, 2, and 3. Assuming four cores of course.

Comment: This sound feasible for me. How do I do this in practice? Command line spells?

Comment: @Juha no, right-click the process in the details tab

Answer (score 0):

You could call the [`SetProcessAffinityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on every process but yours with a mask that excludes just the core that will "belong" to your process, and use it on your process to set it to run just on this core (or, even better, [`SetThreadAffinityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just on the thread that does the time-critical task).

Comment: If you do that then the process is killed and relaunches again with the same name, must the mask still be re-applied?

Answer (score 0):

> Given the infrequency of changes I think the CPU cache is getting cold.

That sounds very strange.

Let's assume your polling thread and the writing thread are on different cores.

The polling thread will be reading the shared memory address and so will be caching the data.  That cache line is probably marked as exclusive.  Then the write thread finally writes; first, it reads the cache line of memory in (so that line is now marked as shared on both cores) and then it writes.  Writing causes the polling thread CPU's cache line to be marked as invalid.  The polling thread then comes to read again; if it reads while the writing thread still has the data cached, it will read from the second cores cache, invalidating its cache line and taking ownership for itself.  There's a lot of bus traffic overhead to do this.

Another issue is that the writing thread, if it doesn't write often, will almost certainly lose the TLB entry for the page with the shared memory address.  Recalculating the physical address is a long, slow process.  Since the polling thread polls often, possibly that page is always in that cores TLB; and in that sense, you might well do better, in latency terms, to have both threads on the same core.  (Although if they're both compute intensive, they might interfere destructively and that cost could be much higher - I can't know, as I don't know what the threads are doing).

One thing you could do is use a hyperthread on the writing thread core; if you know early on you're going to write, get the hyperthread to read the shared memory address.  This will load the TLB and cache while the writing thread is still busy computing, giving you parallelism.

Answer (score -1):

The Win32 function [SetThreadAffinityMask()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.